# Delete All Duplicate keys and values from MultiArray

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to Delete duplicates completely(**NOT REMOVING DUPLICATES AND GETTING UNIQUE RATHER DELETING THEM ALL**) from two arrays. I have tried using `array_merge`, `array_filter`, `array_unique` and `unseting` the values. All just remove duplicates but does not delete all the duplicate keys and values.

**Input:**

```
// ARRAY 1
array(
[0] => Array ( 
    [user] => user1 
    [sending_time] => 1536513874 
    [read_time] => 1536567672 
    [content] => def 
    [recipient_status] => read 
)
);

// ARRAY 2
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [user] => 2224  
    [sending_time] => 1536513903 
    [read_time] => 1536513941 
    [content] => sad 
    [recipient_status] => read 
) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [user] => 3310  
    [sending_time] => 1536513903
    [read_time] => 1536513941 
    [content] => sad 
    [recipient_status] => read 
)
[2] => Array ( 
    [user] => user1 
    [sending_time] => 1536513874 
    [read_time] => 1536567672 
    [content] => def 
    [recipient_status] => read 
)
```

)

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED?**

```
array_merge($array2, $array1);
```

After using array_merge then using : `array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);`

**THE EXPECTED OUTPUT IS:**

As in the above two arrays ,the sub-array with key [user] having value `user1` is similar I want to delete both of these so the output should be:

```
array (
    [0] => 
    array (
      [user] => 2023,
      [sending_time] => 1536513903,
      [read_time] => 1536513941,
      [content] => sad,
      [recipient_status] => read,
    )
    [1] => 
    array (
      [user] => 3310,
      [sending_time] => 1536513903,
      [read_time] => 1536513941,
      [content] => sad,
      [recipient_status] => read,
    )
)
```

Comment: You might want to post a more minimal question, which makes it easy to see what the issue is with duplicates in your data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated!

Comment: I would suggest turning on the warnings. The code above spawns about 50 of them. Anything that looks like `[user]` is an illegal index. Basically `user` is undefined and gets converted to `'user'`, and `['user']` produces an illegal offset.

Comment: I tried to convert it from json encoded

Comment: @MR_AMDEV, Php has at least one function to decode JSON - `json_decode()`

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin ok i just tried to show through `print_r` of php

Comment: @MR_AMDEV, Coudl you perhaps provide the actual code? It would be easier for everyone to find a problem. Output of Print_r is not very suitable for creating verifiable code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184251/discussion-between-eugene-anisiutkin-and-mr-amdev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of [array-filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [array-search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array-column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

Consider use the following:

```
// creating example arrays
$arr1 = array(array("user" => "user1", "content" => "def"));
$a = array("user" => 2224, "content" => "aaa");
$b = array("user" => 3310, "content" => "bbb");
$c = array("user" => "user1", "content" => "ccc");
$arr2 = array($a, $b, $c);

// filter $arr2 as element that are not exist in $arr1
$arr = array_filter($arr2, function($elem) use ($arr1) {
        return (array_search($elem["user"], array_column($arr1, 'user')) === false);
});
```

This will return in `$arr` only the ither 2 elements in `$arr2`

Comment: Can you please confirm? On my side this is also giving the same results : `$MSGS_array = array_diff_key($array2, $array1);`

Comment: Just left my computer - will check when I get back

Comment: Works on my examples like a charm. Also seems to be far better than `array_diff_key`, because `array_diff_key` is not suitable for multidimentional arrays.

Comment: @MR_AMDEV I tried `array_diff_key` does not work - it compare the key (integer in your case) so my test case fails because user1 was at key 0 in the first array but key 2 at the second one

Answer (score 0):

You could try to loop through the arrays and only add nondublicates to another array and return this array.

Comment: An example perhaps? anyway, there is `array_unique()` function. It should do the trick in most cases.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin `array_unique` does not delete all of the matching/similar but it removes the duplicates and returns one of them which is the last one in index.But i just want to remove all duplicates and do not want to get one of them.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `array_merge_recursive()`

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($arr2, $arr1);
```

#### Resources

- [array_merge_recursive - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)